# Remote Desktop connect with SSH client

Tags: ssh, connection, remote

I have went through openssh server set up but it seems all command line. Is there a gui for it? 
The main option I am looking for is a way to know people connected to the server real time and notification when people connect.

Also is there a way to remote connect to a desktop, terminal only, via ssh clients (just by using default remote desktop connect option instead of starting a server)?

What I am trying to achieve is basically remote connect to my personal desktop (Ubuntu 14.04) via ssh clients and just need to access the terminal. The desktop I am remote connecting to must notify of people connecting real time and allow me to control who connects to it.

Any solution for this will be of great help.

Comment: Putty is a client, my question is more about how I should let clients connect to my Ubuntu desktop

Answer (score 0):

**No**, to connect via ssh you need a ssh server, and ssh is command line only.

I tried starting a desktop environment via ssh. It didn't worked.